# How to use routes in Flutter outside BuildContext?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use routes in Flutter. When a tab is pressed, I want to navigate to that page. I have included the code I tried.

However, this doesn't work because context is undefined.

Is there a way I can use routes to accomplish this function?

```
void choiceAction(String choice) {
  if (choice == Tabs.Settings) {
    print('Settings');
  }
  else if (choice == Tabs.Tutorial) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => OnBoarding()),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:**
I am calling choiceAction from a PopupMenuButton.

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.settings,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: 30.0,
                                      ),
                                      onSelected: choiceAction("Tutorial", context),
                                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return Tabs.choices.map((String choice) {
                                          return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                            value: choice,
                                            child: Text(choice),
                                          );
                                        }).toList();
                                      },
                                    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PopupMenuButton (widget), the BuildContext is always visible.

How to use PopupMenuButton is different than such a thing.
The type specified in PopupMenuButton#onSelected is type `void Function(T value)`.

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
  onSelected: (str) {
    choiceAction("Tutorial", context);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `BuildContext` to the variables for your `choiceAction` method and whenever you call this method, pass the current context.

```
void choiceAction(String choice, BuildContext context) {
  if (choice == Tabs.Settings) {
    print('Settings');
  }
  else if (choice == Tabs.Tutorial) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OnBoarding()));
  }
}
```

Call the `choiceAction` method from somewhere

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RaisedButton(
    "Go to next page",
    onPressed: choiceAction("choice 1", context),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm calling the choiceAction from the onSelected in a PopupMenuButton<String> and it won't let me use a type void.